# ARCGIS: Hide polygons resulting from a spatial query

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, spatial-query

I have a bunch of web layers and want to hide all polygons that are intersect with a given geometry/other layer.

I filter these intersecting polygons using spatial query, but then I don't know how to hide them. I was thinking that can manipulate renderer of resulting polygons, something like: hide(), opacity = 0, visible=false... Is this right approach, or I need first to query polygons that are not intersecting and then add results to a new layer and render only them? In such case what should be query.spatialRelationship?

Here is my query:

```
    view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(layerView){
       var query = layer.createQuery();
       query.geometry = new Extent({ 
         xmin: 6902682.7633,
         ymin: -3519872.5095,
         xmax: 11221869.7958,
         ymax: -2276864.0272,
         spatialReference: 102100
       });
       query.spatialRelationship = "intersects";    

       layer.queryFeatures(query).then(function(results){
         for (var index in results.features) { 
           //hide as manipulate its rendering    
         }    
        // or something like layerView.highlight(results.features)    
       })
    });
```

Comment: not sure how many features we are talking about in this area but after you have the intersecting features that you want to hide; you could update the featurelayer's definition expression to something like `objectid NOT IN (1, 2, 3, 4...)`

Comment: Exactly what I did: I query for the ObjectIds and then set the layer's definitionExpression = "NOT OBJECTID IN (" + queryResults.join() + ")" but isn't it a slow operation if there are a large amount of polygon features

Comment: Just FYI - your value for `query.spatialRelationship` is incorrect. [API docs](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jsapi/query-amd.html#constants) say it should be taken from the Constants list for the Query class.

Comment: @Juffy I think he is using v4.x of the API. See: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-support-Query.html#spatialRelationship

Comment: Yes, I'm using 4.10 of JS API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to display the features at all, you can use a [QueryTask](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-tasks-QueryTask.html) to retrieve only the features that intersects the extent from the MapService. Then you could create a FeatureLayer with the results.

```
require(["esri/tasks/QueryTask", "esri/tasks/support/Query", "esri/geometry/Extent", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"], function(QueryTask, Query, Extent, FeatureLayer){
  var layerUrl = " ... "; // Represents the REST endpoint for your layer
  var queryTask = new QueryTask({
    url: layerUrl 
  });
  var query = new Query();
  query.returnGeometry = true;
  query.outFields = ["*"];
  query.geometry = new Extent({ 
     xmin: 6902682.7633,
     ymin: -3519872.5095,
     xmax: 11221869.7958,
     ymax: -2276864.0272,
     spatialReference: 102100
  });
  query.spatialRelationship = "intersects";

  // When resolved, create the featureLayer with the results
  queryTask.execute(query).then(function(results){
    var layer = new FeatureLayer({
      source: results.features
    });
  });
});
```

This answer might be the best from a performance stand of view because the intersection is made on the server side and the client won't have to download features that are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the visible property of the graphics to false

```
view.whenLayerView(layer).then(function(layerView){
   var query = layer.createQuery();
   query.geometry = new Extent({ 
     xmin: 6902682.7633,
     ymin: -3519872.5095,
     xmax: 11221869.7958,
     ymax: -2276864.0272,
     spatialReference: 102100
   });
   query.spatialRelationship = "intersects";    

   layer.queryFeatures(query).then(function(results){
     for (var index in results.features) { 
       results.features[index].visible = false;  
     }    
    // or something like layerView.highlight(results.features)    
   })
});
```